# Installing cocos2d template for XCode4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to install cocoa2d template for XCode 4. I tried installing and it says it installed fine but I don't see the templates there. I restarted my computer too...

```
sudo ./install-templates.sh -u -f
cocos2d-iphone template installer



Installing cocos2d iOS template
----------------------------------------------------

removing old libraries: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Application/
...creating destination directory: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Application/
...copying template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Ahmed/.Trash/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/templates/cocos2d_app/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocos2d files
...copying cocos2d dependency files
...copying CocosDenshion files
...copying cocoslive files
...copying cocoslive dependency files
done!



Installing cocos2d iOS + box2d template
----------------------------------------------------

removing old libraries: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Box2d Application/
...creating destination directory: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Box2d Application/
...copying template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Ahmed/.Trash/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/templates/cocos2d_box2d_app/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocos2d files
...copying cocos2d dependency files
...copying CocosDenshion files
...copying cocoslive files
...copying cocoslive dependency files
...copying Box2D files
done!



Installing cocos2d iOS + chipmunk template
----------------------------------------------------

removing old libraries: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Chipmunk Application/
...creating destination directory: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Chipmunk Application/
...copying template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Ahmed/.Trash/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/templates/cocos2d_chipmunk_app/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-40/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocos2d files
...copying cocos2d dependency files
...copying CocosDenshion files
...copying cocoslive files
...copying cocoslive dependency files
...copying Chipmunk files
done!



Installing cocos2d Mac template
----------------------------------------------------

removing old libraries: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Application - Mac/
...creating destination directory: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/cocos2d Application - Mac/
...copying template files
...copying cocos2d files
...copying CocosDenshion files
done!
...copying file templates
removing old libraries: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/
...creating destination directory: /Users/Ahmed/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates/cocos2d 0.99.5/



Installing CCNode file templates...
----------------------------------------------------

done!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try these instructions?
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1412

> $ mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
>
> $ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
>
> $ tar xzvf cocos2d-1.0.0-beta_templates.tar.gz

Comment: perfect ! I was facing this issue. I just read your answer & It worked like a charm ! Thankx +1 surely !